# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an error when trying to make a data listing request:

**MyModel:**

```py
import uuid
import time

from django.db import models
from a.models import ModelA
from b.models import ModelB


def upload_location(instance, filename):
    filebase, extension = filename.split('.')
    milliseconds = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

    return 'a_id__%s/%s__%s.%s' % (instance.a_id, instance.name, milliseconds, extension)


class Attachment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location)

    a = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelA,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    b = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelB,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Error:
[image]

**I've tried the following ways and without success...**

```py
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name
```

***This error happens when I try to open the screen to attach a new item via the "Django-Admin"***

Comment: Can you share your form?

Comment: @bdbd i not have form, i using default django-admin and backend-api... 
In backend api the problem doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

### Conflicting serializers

Encountered the same error when I used two different serializers for listing.

I just had to to remove the line  **serializer_class = Serializer_one**

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    # serializer_class = Serializer_one
    def list(self, request):
        .....
        ........
        serializer = Serializer_two(some_queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```